# Javascript Promise chaning with Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

So i am having some trouble with a promise, i cant figure it out.
The code is quite long but i am going to simplify it a little.

The basic problem is, getDataSet1AndPostToMysql gets some data and updates values into mysql, after that, i want getDataAndPerformAction to get some data from mysql, perform some actions, and then update some fields into mysql, and then, i want to close the connection.

If  I only execute getDataSet1AndPostToMysql and write a .then() to close the connection, it all works like a charm.

The problem is that, when i add the second promise function to the first .then it doesnt work anymore.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!!!

```js
function getDataSet1AndPostToMysql(param){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   //perform some actions with data        
  var sql = "UPDATE urls SET value=1 WHERE data='" + valueX + "'";
  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
  })

   resolve();
   })
}

function getDataAndPerformAction{
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
    //Get data back from mysql
    //Do things with data      
    var sql = "UPDATE urls SET depth="+depth+1+" WHERE url='" + url + "'";
    connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("update done")
    })
  
        resolve();
    })

}

getDataSet1AndPostToMysql.then(()=>{
  getDataAndPerformAction()
  }).then(()=>{
  connection.end()
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise from `getDataAndPerformAction` in the `then` otherwise `then` just returns undefined and then next `then` doesn't have anything to wait for.

```
getDataSet1AndPostToMysql.then(()=>{
    return getDataAndPerformAction() // return this
}).then(()=>{
    connection.end()
})
```

You could simplify by not using the braces:

```
getDataSet1AndPostToMysql.then(()=> getDataAndPerformAction()) // this implicitly returns
.then(()=> connection.end())
```

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for the reply. Tried this but still getting "Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit". The connections take quite a while since i have to make hundreds of updates to de ddbb. Could that be te problem?

Comment: @Rever92 You are not resolving your promises correctly.  You call `resolve()` right after you invoke `connection.query`.  You need to `resolve()` inside it's callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass result and err to the promise, plus handler the case where there is an error.

```
function getDataSet1AndPostToMysql(param){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //perform some actions with data        
        var sql = "UPDATE urls SET value=1 WHERE data='" + valueX + "'";
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) resolve(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
function getDataAndPerformAction() {
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
        var sql = "UPDATE urls SET depth="+depth+1+" WHERE url='" + url + "'";
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

function cleanup(connection) {
    connection.end();
}
var boundCleanup = cleanup.bind(connection);
getDataSet1AndPostToMysql.then(getDataAndPerformAction)
    .then(boundCleanup, boundCleanup);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! Actually, to simplyfy it i didnt write it, but the connection in both cases in inside of a for loop, thats why i didnt put the resolve inside... Any other option here? :)

Comment: Instead of using a loop, you call Promise.all on a iterable (usually an array), then do the cleanup.
var updates = /* an array of promises */
Promise.all(updates).then(/* error handling*/);

Comment: Hm... the problem is the for in loop i am using is on an object... how could i go around it?